# запрет редактирования колонки qtableview

Tags: qt

как запретить редактировать колонку

```
 setTable("orders");
 setEditStrategy(QSqlRelationalTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
 setJoinMode(QSqlRelationalTableModel::LeftJoin);
 setRelation(fieldIndex("crmuser_id"),QSqlRelation("users","idusers","name"));

QVariant CRMModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if(role == Qt::BackgroundColorRole)
    {
        if(QSqlRelationalTableModel::data(this->index(index.row(), 16)).toString() == "bank")
        {
            return QColor(Qt::yellow);
        }
        else if(QSqlRelationalTableModel::data(this->index(index.row(), 16)).toString() == "yandex")
        {
            return QColor(Qt::green);
        }
    }
    else if(role==Qt::EditRole)
    {
        return QSqlRelationalTableModel::data(index,role);
    }
    else if(role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
        return QSqlRelationalTableModel::data(index,role);
    }
    return QVariant();
}


select();
```

т.е чтобы стандартный делегат показывал связи в таблицы но комбобокса не было. И вообще чтобы нельзя ничего менять было в этом поле.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте переопределить метод [flags](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#flags) и вернуть [флаги](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qt.html#ItemFlag-enum), например `return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable;`

Через `index` определите [колонку](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html#column) и возвратите для нужной колонки нужные флаги

Answer (score 0):

Боюсь напутать, но когда-то нечто подобное я делал так:

```
class NotEditableDelegate : public QItemDelegate {
  Q_OBJECT
  public:
    QWidget* createEditor(QWidget*, const QStyleOptionViewItem&,
                          const QModelIndex& ) const {return 0;}
  protected:
    virtual void drawFocus(QPainter *, const QStyleOptionViewItem&,
                           const QRect & ) const {return;}
};
```

Comment: все равно стандартный делегат срабатывает. не помогло (

Comment: Для "разборок" нужен "синтетический" пример. Просто чтобы воспроизвести и протестировать. Сделаешь - разберемся. А пока просто подозрение, что приведенный выше делегат не подключается должным образом.

Comment: Выше добавил полное описание модели. Может из-за EditRole.